# Angular.js missing $scope update on page load

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I've got a bit of an interesting situation where I have a weather app, and on loading the app, I want to get the users last position, and the last forecast they saw, and display that, while the app goes and gets the updated forecast.

In my controller, I construct the forecast view like this

```
function constructWeather(forecast){
        if(!forecast.data.list){
            $scope.loading='weather-error';
            return;
        }
        var today = forecast.data.list[0];
        console.log($scope.date);
        var date = $scope.date;
        $scope.print_date = $filter('date')(date,'EEEE, MMMM, d');
        $scope.print_time = $filter('date')(date,'h:mm a');
        $scope.weather = formatWeather(today,date,true);
        $scope.city =  $scope.position.name || forecast.data.city.name;

        $scope.forecast = (function(){
                            var day_list=[];
                            for(var d=1; d<6; d++){
                                var day_weather = formatForecast(forecast.data.list[d],date,false);
                                day_list.push(day_weather);
                            }
                            return day_list;
                        })();

        $scope.loading = 'weather-loaded';

    }
```

This works fine when getting a new weather forecast, but when I am trying to reload the old forecast, all the $scope.print_date, $scope.weather, etc. etc. work fine, but ONLY the $scope.forecast the one executed within the anonymous function, does not display.

I've output to the console, and I see the day_weather is being built, but angular isn't updating.

In the template, it is loaded via

```
 &lt;div class="day" ng-repeat="day in forecast"&gt;
            &lt;div class="date"&gt;{{ day.print_date }}&lt;/div&gt;
            &lt;div class="long-day"&gt;{{ day.long_day }}&lt;/div&gt;
            &lt;div class="img {{weather.conditions | lowercase}}"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
            &lt;div class="temps"&gt;
                &lt;span class="degrees"&gt;{{ day.weather.temps.max }}&lt;/span&gt;
                &lt;span class="min degrees"&gt;{{ day.weather.temps.min }}&lt;/span&gt;
            &lt;/div&gt;
        &lt;/div&gt;
```

and of course, no divs are added to the page.

I've tried to run a `$scope.$apply` but it returns an error that I'm already in a digest cycle.

Is there another way to tell Angular that the $scope.forecast has new data?

Comment: have you tried not using an anonymous function?

Comment: try wrapping that part in a $timeout(function() { ... }, 0).

Comment: Why are you adding a function to the global scope instead of to $scope?

Comment: I've tried not using the anonymous function, I've tried timeouts, I'm not sure what function you mean is on the global Scope Andres. Do you mean the constructWeather? I didn't assume that every function should be attached to $scope, but I can try that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using closure like you did, works like that:

1. function declaration: `(function() {...})`
2. function execution: `()`

So to the `$scope.forcast` the result of `2.` is assigned. It is a completely static object.

If you want to execute this function many times, declare it this way:

```
 $scope.forecast = function(){ ... };
```

and in you mark-up use it like that:

```
ng-repeat="day in forecast()"
```

[PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/QzI0bGszNUQBs2ZaVUxx?p=preview) that shows it in action!

---

**UPDATE**
`$scope.forecast = (function(){...})()` can be replaced with:

```
$scope.getForecast = function () {...};
$scope.forecast = $scope.getForecast();
```

Then in your mark-up you can do something like that:

```
ng-repeat="day in (forecast=getForecast())"
```

For sure, it cannot be anything worse than what you had previously. If there is still some delay due to -- *for example* -- some asynchronous call, you should manually synchronize properties you want to be updated together.

Comment: Interesting, you do realize that what I had was a self-executing function, right? I finished it with `()` which from my understand runs the execution. Actually, I know it does because I could see the execution run in the console, it is just the scope that wasn't displaying. 

Your solution does work, I moved the forecast function into it's own function, and then call that function from within `constructWeather`. Unfortunately, this way there is a delay between when the original weather is displayed, and when the rest of the forecast is displayed, which doesn't look great.

Comment: @pedalpete strange. for sure there is a solution to have no delay. could you show code of your controller. will update shortly my answer -- please check if it works for you.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by 'manually synchronize properties'? How can I do that in Angular?

Comment: @pedalpete I meant: first collect all the data that should be displayed and only once you grabbed all of them update the view. Probably the most elegant solution would be to use `promises`. But -- without seeing, what you actually mean by *delay* -- it is really hard to find a suitable solution.